# Angular 6 SPA with Identity Server - Storing tokens

Tags: angular, access-token, identityserver4

I am developing a Angular 6 based SPA which accesses back end API for data. This application and APIs have been secured using Identity Server 4. I am using the `oidc-client` library to interact with the Identity Server. Whilst the application is working quite well, there is one aspect that needs to be addressed.

After authentication, when the user is in the application and refreshes the browser  (using F5), the authentication tokens that are returned by the Identity Server are lost. To avoid this, there have been suggestions to keep the token in the `local storage`. However, there also have been blogs that advise against this due to possible XSS attacks.

Has anyone done anything different? What are the possible other routes I can take to address this issue?

Thanks
Sushil

Comment: To which blogs are you referring? Did you read this and linked blogs: https://leastprivilege.com/2019/01/18/an-alternative-way-to-secure-spas-with-asp-net-core-openid-connect-oauth-2-0-and-proxykit/ ?

Answer (score 0):

The general suggestion is to use *Local storage* for long-life data and *Session storage* for session-wise sensitive information, similar to how you use persistent and session cookies for server-driven web apps.
That does not prevent XSS attacks possibility, but minimizes it to the time when the tab with your SPA is open.
And, yes, you can switch (back) to the cookie auth with *HttpOnly* and *Lax* or *Strict* SameSite mode. Much more secure, but with possible compatibility issues.